# error while importing express

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, ecmascript-6

I am using intellij 15 to my typescript server application - which transpiles to js (obviously). The problem is that I am unable to import 'express' lib. The lib is installed and present in my dependencies and placed in the node_modules dir, but still I am getting the following error:
[image]
Here is the express lib under node modules:
[image]
and here is the package.json file:
[image]

What did I do wrong?

Note: when writing:

```
let express = require('express');
```

The ide not giving any error - only tslint that asks to use import instead of require.

Comment: Could it be complaining about `express` being under `node_modules`, i.e. not in the same path? Also iirc doesn't `express` need to be a file, `express.js`? I haven't used ES6 modules much but that's what I recall.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the tsd file of express and changed my import as follow:

```
import * as express from 'express';
```